# Xamarin Visual Studio and Code version coupling

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Our team has noticed that for Xamarin Development from a Windows Machine using Visual Studio, there is an implied version of XCode that must be installed. It appears that this is a one-way drive where XCode updates require Visual Studio to upgrade. Are these rules documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/).  Basically if you install a VS/Xamarin.iOS update that introduces support for iOS version X, then you need the version of Xcode that supports iOS version X.